# Angular6 not navigating on lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

*Here's my home routes*

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dummy',
        loadChildren: '../dummy/dummy.module#DummyModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

*And here's my component route which I want to load*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DummyComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DummyRoutingModule { }
```

But it not loads my component. Only url is changing

[image]

any idea what's going on? there's my folder structure

[image]

[image]

*App.component.html*

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

*dummy.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DummyRoutingModule } from './dummy-routing.module';
import { DummyComponent } from './dummy/dummy.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DummyRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [DummyComponent]
})
export class DummyModule { }
```

Comment: have you added `router-outlet` ?

Comment: yeah inside `app.component`. Expected behavior is to display `dummy component ` content instead of home @PardeepJain

Comment: that mean you dont want to show `home` right?

Comment: yes. I want to replace it with dummy component

Comment: please post your app.coomponent.html file

Comment: I've updated question

Comment: post your dummy.module.ts and DummyComponent file also you have some confussion your folder structure why contains dummy within dummy can you explain

Comment: @KarnanMuthukumar I updated question. second one is for component

Comment: top level routing module should use `forRoot()` and not `forChild()` if i'm not mistaken

Comment: @Cétia `app-routing.module` is the top level http://prntscr.com/k2dtzb

Answer (score 0):

Update one thing let try this once.And let me know

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DummyRoutingModule } from './dummy-routing.module';
import { DummyComponent } from './dummy/dummy.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DummyRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [DummyComponent],
  exports:[DummyComponent] //added this line newly
})
export class DummyModule { }
```

Make sure you have entered some data in dummy component.html file

change this also

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(homeRoutes)], //forChild to forRoot
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

@cetia said this one.

Comment: result is the same